# Trapping two timeedit schedule

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datetime

I have this sample form which sets and compare two time schedules.

[image]

I want to trap the time in which the second schedule can't be set if its between the first schedule(time start and time end).

**For example: 
First Sched: 
8:00:00 AM to 10:00:00 AM
I want to trap the second schedule so that it can't be set between the first schedule like 8:30:00 AM, 9:00:00 AM, 9:30:00 etc. . .it will be set as 10:00:00 AM or above. How can I possibly do that?**

I've done some sort of codes but figuring how to do that is hard for me. Can anyone help?

Here's my sample code:

```
 Private Sub Test_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        If timeStart.EditValue > timeEnd.EditValue Then
            XtraMessageBox.Show("Time end must higher than time start", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand)
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf timeStart.EditValue = timeEnd.EditValue Then
            XtraMessageBox.Show("Time start must not be equal to time end", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand)
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf timeStart1.EditValue < timeEnd.EditValue Then
            XtraMessageBox.Show("Invalid", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand)
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf timeEnd1.EditValue < timeEnd.EditValue Then
            XtraMessageBox.Show("Invalid", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand)
            Exit Sub
        End If


    End Sub
```

Comment: I advise you to rename the controls as `timeStart1`, `timeEnd1`, `timeStart2` and `timeEnd2`.

Comment: i'd go even more descriptive `firstScheduleTimeStart`, `firstScheduleTimeEnd`, `secondScheduleTimeStart`, `secondScheduleTimeEnd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim t1Start = timeStart.EditValue
Dim t1End = timeEnd.EditValue
Dim t2Start = timeStart1.EditValue
Dim t2End = timeEnd1.EditValue

If (t2Start >= t1Start And t2Start <= t1End) Or _
    (t2End >= t1Start And t2End <= t1End) Or _
    (t1Start >= t2Start And t1Start <= t2End) Then

    XtraMessageBox.Show("The times should not overlap", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand)

End If
```

Four situations is possible:

```
1st range   <------->      <------->   <------->   <------->
2nd range       <----->  <----->        <----->   <--------->
```

- The first comparison pair tests start of the second range being in the middle of the fitst one.
- The second comparison pair tests end of the second range being in the middle of the first one.
- The only remaining situation is when the entier first range is between the second range. Third comparison pair checks the start of the first range being between the second range.

This handles all the situations of overlapping ranges.